# HTML linking to CSS

Tags: html, css

How do I link a CSS sheet to a HTML sheet.

I have

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Hi </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS page is

```
h1 {
    color: orange;
    text-align: center;
}
```

my CSS page is called "CSS" and HTML page is called "HTML"

I right clicked the HTML Doc and pressed open with google chrome i only see a black heading level 1 of "Hi"

Comment: Then, are you seeing the Hi in orange?

Comment: No orange and the "Hi" isn't centered

Comment: what is the file name of you css file? is the css file in the same folder as your html file?

Comment: "CSS" is the name and it is in the same folder (what is the "rel" tag used for in line 3

Comment: it should be CSS.css with extension.

Comment: I didnt add the extention in my comment but it is. I saved it with Sublime Text 2 its for sure a CSS file

Comment: Fixed I had to remove the extention in the link on the html page on line 3

Comment: That is so strange! anyway have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS file needs to be in the same folder as your html page. It also needs to be the exact same case, capital CSS lowercase css extension. (CSS.css)

```
folder/index.html
folder/CSS.css
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things could be the issue here:

1. **Keep your filenames lowercase.**  Linux servers are case sensitive where windows servers are not.  Keeping your filenames in lowercases avoids problems should you ever need to switch.
2. **Make sure you have a doctype set up**, otherwise your browser will revert to quirks mode and likely cause problems.
3. **Make sure your files are in the appropriate locations**.  Because your html links directly to CSS.css and uses no relative pathing, they should be within the same folder.